# How To Host FastAPI Application With Firebase Hosting

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, fastapi, firebase-hosting

This is my first time using Firebase hosting. I am following [this](https://youtu.be/P0x0LmiknJc?t=563) tutorial to host my sample FastAPI application. But I cannot access the endpoint I have set in my app. I am pretty sure I have messed up on the build command. I cannot figure out what to put there.

This is my FastAPI app -

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/hello')
async def generate_avatar(request: Request):
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Success"}, status_code=200)
```

This is the `firebase-hosting-merge.yml` file generated by the Firebase CLI -

```yaml
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: 'pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt && gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app -D'
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AGENT_AVATAR_GENERATION }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: agent-avatar-generation
```

I also have written a Dockerfile and I tried to use the docker build command in the merge workflow file to build this image instead of running python commands directly, but still, I can't get it to work.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt

# Copy rest of the files
COPY ./app /app

CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "app.main:app", "-d"]
```

No matter how I try to access the `/hello` endpoint, I keep getting a 404 response. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out with this.

Thank you.